Copy a row but skip a couple columns into a new worksheet
I need to copy specific columns from a row into an existing worksheet, but into the same columns of the other worksheet. Example:
In row 2 I want to copy C2 and then F2:M2into the next available row in the next worksheet into C and F:M.
I have tried variations of the code below but cannot figure out how to achieve this. Any help please.
This is the original code:
Sub Create_ROC_Case_126()

Dim ROCCasesDest

ROCCasesDest = Worksheets("ROC Cases").Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
        .Range("F8:M8").Copy
    End With
    
    With Sheets("ROC Cases")
        .Range("F" & ROCCasesDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub

This is one attempt:
Sub Create_ROC_Case_126()

Dim ROCCasesDest

ROCCasesDest = Worksheets("ROC Cases").Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
        .Range("C8, F8:M8").Copy
    End With
    
    With Sheets("ROC Cases")
        .Range("C, F:M" & ROCCasesDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub


Two lines: Sheets("ROC Cases").Range("C" & ROCCasesDest).Value = Sheets("Dock Door Status").Range("C8").Value, Sheets("ROC Cases").Range("F" & ROCCasesDest & ":M" & ROCCasesDest).Value = Sheets("Dock Door Status").Range("F8:M8").Value.

@BigBen That works perfect. Thank you. Please post as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

I will admit that I would not have thought of this approach as it almost seems backwards in its construction. But I get how it works. Pretty sweet.

It's fairly well known technique, covered here for example. I've heard it referred to as "value transfer."

On a side note, if a similar version of this code is supposed to be in a loop, each next series of values would overwrite the previous ones in the same row because you're determining the last row in column B which is not written to. If you need it to be column B then determine the last row before the loop and include ROCCasesDest = ROCCasesDest + 1 after the write operation inside the loop.

@VBasic2008 I used "B" because that is the beginning column in my range for that worksheet. So, I guess the next logical question is do I need to use the first column in a range when determining the last row or can I just use A as a default? (I know this is off topic, but it doesn't seem worthy of it's own question in SO)

Start with the legendary answer to "Find last used cell in Excel VBA". It will depend on what your data looks like. End(xlUp) ... + 1 will do if a column surely contains a value in the last row. If it's a list (contiguous range, one row of headers) that starts in A1 then I prefer With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: FirstRow = .Rows(1).Offset(.Rows.Count).Row: End With. If it's the only thing on the worksheet and it is well formatted (no formats below the data) then I like even With ws.UsedRange: FirstRow = .Row + .Rows.Count: End With.

I actually just learned about UsedRange the other day. Very useful. Thank you for the insights and help.
